# Ошибка при обходе матрицы спиралью

Tags: c++

Написал код обхода матрицы спиралью, она все делает правильно, кроме заключительного шага, в чем ошибка, никак не могу найти?

```
int* helix(int **matrix, int size) {
  int* new_matrix = new int[size * size];
  int count = 0;
  int sup_var = size / 2; // кол во проходов спиралью
  for (int i = 0; i < sup_var; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < size - i; j++) {
      new_matrix[count] = matrix[i][j]; // строка вправо
      count++;
    }
    for (int k = 1; k < size - i; k++) { // столбец вниз
      new_matrix[count] = matrix[k][size - i - 1]; 
      //cout << endl << new_matrix[count] << endl;
      count++;
    }
    for( int j = size - i - 1; j > i; j--) { // строка влево
      new_matrix[count] = matrix[size - i - 1][j - 1];
      count++;
    }
    for (int k = size - i - 1; k > 1; k--) {
      new_matrix[count] = matrix[k-1][i];
      count++;
    }
  }
  cout << endl << new_matrix[15];
  return new_matrix;
}
```

[image: вот как она его проходит]

[image: Вот матрица]

Она проходит все верно, кроме последнего шага, выводит последние 2 элемента как 1 5, а должен 5 1

[image: результат]

Answer (score 0):

У Вашем коде, `1` выводиться еще раз на первой итерации цикла, который проходится вниз.

Строка вниз (i = 1, вторая итерация главного цикла)
`for (int k = 1; k < size - i; k++) {`:

- 1 итерация: `k = 1, 1 < 4 - 1, m[1][4 - 1 - 1] = 1`
- 2 итерация: `k = 2, 2 < 4 - 1, m[2][4 - 1 - 1] = 5`

Видим, что сначала выводиться 1, а потом 5. Соответственно надо начинать с елемента ниже.

P.S. Странно, что после 5 не вывелась еще 1. У Вас код не соответствует выводу.

Можете переделать так:

```
int* helix(int** matrix, int size)
{
    int* new_matrix = new int[size * size];

    for (int i = 0, c = 0, i <= size / 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < size - i; j++) new_matrix[c++] = matrix[i][j];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size - i - 1; j++) new_matrix[c++] = matrix[j][size - i - 1];
        for (int j = size - i - 1; c <= size * size && j >= i; j--) new_matrix[c++] = matrix[size - i - 1][j];
        for (int j = size - i - 2; j > i; j--) new_matrix[c++] = matrix[j][i];
    }

    return new_matrix;
}
```