# Почему не работает обход матрицы по спирали с центра?

Tags: c++

Написал код, он работает, например на матрице 4х4, только до 12 элемента в массиве, начиная с new_matrix[13] - выдает не те значения, с чем связано?

```
int *helix_center (int** matrix, int size) {
  int* new_matrix = new int[size * size];
  int count = 0;
  int step = 1;
  int sup_var = size / 2;
  int sup_var_2 = sup_var;
  new_matrix[count] = matrix[sup_var][sup_var_2];
  count++;
  while( step < size ) { 
    for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
      if (sup_var_2 != 0)
        new_matrix[count] = matrix[sup_var][--sup_var_2];
      count++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
      if(sup_var != 0) 
        new_matrix[count] = matrix[--sup_var][sup_var_2];
      count++;
    }
    step++;
    for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
      new_matrix[count] = matrix[sup_var][++sup_var_2];
      count++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
      new_matrix[count] = matrix[++sup_var][sup_var_2];
      count++;
    }
    step++;
  }
 return new_matrix;
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1177211/398802

Comment: Это разные реализации, там начиная с первого элемента, тут с центрального

Comment: Так а совет то тот-же, учись дебажить.